# Cannot register voice action in Android wearable app

Tags: android, wear-os

I've tried hard to register my app to accept voice commands –– any command, system or app provided –– but I keep on failing. I wonder if I am using the intents correctly? Can someone tell me if my `AdrodManifest.xml` for the Wearable app looks correct?

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

    <activity
        android:name="com.volkanunsal.mtawear.WearableMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

EDIT:

Here is the gist of the manifest files:

https://gist.github.com/volkanunsal/d7c8f09103f49f3ba822

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html

Comment: That didn't work. Here are the manifest filles. https://gist.github.com/volkanunsal/d7c8f09103f49f3ba822

Comment: Looks like it should work. Have you selected the action for "Take a note" on the android wear app?

Comment: When I press that, my app's icon is not coming up. There are two other apps that I see in the dialogue, but not mine. :(

Comment: Are you sure the app is installed on the wearable? It should appear under "Start.." if it is?

Comment: Yep, I see my app under start.

Comment: Try my new answer I've just tested it myself